# Javascript Display Images based on File Extension

Tags: javascript, html, django

Im working on this Django Template's javascript which displays a file extension icon based on  file extension
the script is working fine but for only 1 ID ,I know it's because I am using GetElementById property I tried using GetElementsByClassName still no luck . So I am Lookimg for an effective method to work for all elements on runtime.

**fileview.html**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">

    <h5 id="title">raven.png</h5>
    <img id="image" src="file.png" height="150" width="175">

</div>
<div class="child">

    <h5 id="title">Google-Logo.png</h5>
    <img id="image" src="file.png" height="150" width="175">

</div>
<div class="child">

    <h5 id="title">Panchayath.pdf</h5>
    <img id="image" src="file.png" height="150" width="175">

</div>
</div>
```

Here all the filenames in a object is displayed

**script.js**

```
function changeimg(){ 

     var defaultimg = document.getElementById('image'); 
     var content=document.getElementById('title').innerHTML;
     
     var extension = content.split('.').pop();
    switch(extension)
    {
     case 'pdf':
     defaultimg.src="/images/icons/pdf.png";
     break;
     case 'png':
     case 'gif':
     case 'jpg':
     case 'jpeg':
     case 'tif':
     case 'bmp':
     case 'tiff':
     defaultimg.src="/images/icons/img.png";
     break;
     case 'mp3'
*.......goes on for all extension.....*
     default:
defaultimg.src="/images/icons/file.png";
  }
  setInterval('changeimg();',1000); // To initialize Function
}
```

output :
[image: File view]

What Can I do for function to work on all the IDs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs MUST be unique  - instead use class

and why the interval?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page has loaded
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".child")].forEach(child => { // get all divs with class=child
    const title = child.querySelector(".title"); // get the title div
    const image = child.querySelector(".image"); // get the image 
    const content = title.innerText; // get the text
    const extension = content.split('.').pop();
    switch (extension) {
      case 'py':
        image.src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-adobe/512/267_Python-512.png";
        break;
      case 'png':
      case 'gif':
      case 'jpg':
      case 'jpeg':
      case 'tif':
      case 'bmp':
      case 'tiff':
        image.src = "https://static.thenounproject.com/png/526867-200.png";
        break;
      case 'mp3':
        image.src = "https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/mp3-flat.png";
        break;
      default:
        image.src = "https://freesvg.org/img/matt-icons_file-x-generic.png";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.image {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h5 class="title">file.py</h5>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h5 class="title">Google-Logo.png</h5>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h5 class="title">music.mp3</h5>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h5 class="title">Panchayath.pdf</h5>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you should not work with the ids but with classes, as it is a list of similar objects to iterate over. Update your script to find all images with the containing class `.child` and iterate over them:

```
let childElements = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
```

From there you have to take your logic above and apply it iteratively on each child:

```
Array.from( childElements ).forEach((child) => {
   var defaultimg = child.querySelector('img'); 
   var content=child.querySelector('h5').innerHTML;

   // your logic to find and apply the file-extension.
})
```

Comment: @mplungjan correct, I updated my answer to conform with the given html markup. I would discourage using the id="image", therefor updated to select simply the only img in the child.